# Extracting time from timestamp variable

Tags: php, mysql, time, timestamp

I have a table called "recentdata" in which there are three columns TagID, Timestam and GateNO. I am trying to extract time from the Timestamp variable from a particular row. I am sending all the data through a php code.

Basically first I am storing the data then I want to read the timestamp back and extract time.

Here is my code snippet:

```
$sql = "SELECT Timestamp FROM recentdata Where TagID='".$tagID."'";
$retval = mysqli_query($this->link,$sql) or die('Errant query:  '.$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo "Old Timestamp: {$row['Timestamp']}<br>";
}
//$old_time = strtotime($row['Timestamp']);
//$time1 = date('Gi.s', $RTCtimestamp);
//$time2 = date('Gi.s', $old_time);
list($date1, $time1) = explode('%20', date('d-m-Y%20Gi.s', $RTCtimestamp)); //Line 31
list($date2, $time2) = explode(' ', date('d-m-Y Gi.s', $row['Timestamp'])); //Line 32
```

I have mentioned the line numbers in code comments where I am getting following errors:

```
    Old Timestamp: 2020/02/02 12:3:24
    
    Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\Apache24\htdocs\RFID\connect4.php on line 31
    
    Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\Apache24\htdocs\RFID\connect4.php on line 32
Minutes:-0.55666666666667
```

Here is what being sent to the variables:
$RTCtimestamp = '2020/02/02%2012:3:24'  (This timestamp is the one that I am sending to table. Here, "%20" is written for space as it is how it looks in the browser search tab)
$row['Timestamp'] = '2020/02/02 12:3:24' (This timestamp is read from the MySQL table)

I have tried using **strtotime** function too (which is also provided in the code in commented area)
but, it gives the same two errors. Is there any way to solve this? Please help me find what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: If `$RTCtimestamp = '2020/02/02%2012:3:24'` then it is not a Timestamp and as `date()` required parameter 2 to be a timestamp, you may need a rethink

Comment: Please do an `var_dump($RTCtimestamp);` and show us, thanks

Comment: As I understand it `$row['Timestamp']` is not a timestamp, it's a string representing a date in some format. Can you tell us what format is that?

Comment: I do not see that you have set $RTCtimestamp anywhere in code as well, as @RiggsFolly suggested var_dump($RTCtimestamp) and show us.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I tried doing `var_dump($RTCtimestamp);` and this is the result: `string(18) "2020/02/02 12:3:24".`  
For `var_dump($row['Timestamp']);` i'm getting this error: 
`Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\Apache24\htdocs\RFID\connect4.php on line 32
NULL`

Comment: @Dharman, `$row[Timestamp']` is taken from 'Timestamp' column in the table and the data-type of that column is "TIMESTAMP". I have set it in phpMyAdmin

Comment: Then you should be getting the timestamp like `2020-02-02 12:03:24`

Comment: @Dharman, Yes I am getting it in that format, I also changed $RTCTimestamp format to the same but still same error is showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are not using mysqli properly. Please learn about prepared statements.

To get the data from the database you can use the following code:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT Timestamp FROM recentdata Where TagID=?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $tagID);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

If you are expecting only a single result, there is no need for a loop at all. Just get a single row without a loop.

```
$recentdata = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo "Old Timestamp: {$recentdata['Timestamp']}<br>";
```

To get a time from your timestamp, you need to convert it into a PHP [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object. Then you can use the `format()` method to get the time part only.

```
$dt = new DateTime($recentdata['Timestamp']);
echo "Time ". $dt->format('H:i:s'); // H = hours, i = minutes, s = seconds
```

You can do the same with the data you get from the user. Make sure that the timestamp follows a known format, or use [`date_create_from_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php) and specify your own format.

```
$RTC_dt = new DateTime($RTCtimestamp);
echo "Time ". $RTC_dt->format('H:i:s'); // H = hours, i = minutes, s = seconds
```